# If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are submartingales w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_n$, then $X_n \lor Y_n$ is also.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are submartingales w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_n$, then $X_n \lor Y_n$ is also.

How to prove it?

I try to use definitions that
$$
E[X_n \lor Y_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $\max(X_n,Y_n) \geq X_n $ so $E((\max(X_n,Y_n)|F_{n-1}) \geq E[X_n|F_{n-1}] \geq X_{n-1}$\
Do the same for $Y_n$ and get the result!
(All inequalities are almost sure inequalities). You also have to prove that the max is integrable!